# .NET6 Lambda throws System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-6.0

I have a .NET6 project published as a zip file to AWS Lambda.

When I test it in the AWS console I get the following error:

`Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

In Lambda the architecture is set to `x86_64` with the runtime set to `.NET 6 (C#/PowerShell)`

I am publishing the solution on a Windows machine with the following command:

`dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained .\src\MyApp.Api -c Release -o .\dist\publish`

Can anyone help here?

I believe this error is due to targetting an incorrect architecture but can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Edit:

`MyApp.Api.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <AssemblyName>MyApp.Api</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>MyApp.Api</PackageId>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <RootNamespace>MyApp.Api</RootNamespace>
    <LangVersion>10</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="10.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyApp.Core\MyApp.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`MyApp.runtimeconfig.json`:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "6.0.0"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false
    }
  }
}
```

`MyApp.Api.deps.json`:

```
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0/linux-x64",
    "signature": ""
  },
  // removed for brevity
```

Comment: Are you running on a 32 or 64-bit machine? What is your OS? In your publish folder, what is inside the `x.runtimeconfig.json` file?

Comment: Try `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained .\src\MyApp.Api -c Release -o .\dist\publish` - does that work?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary unfortunately this makes no difference

Comment: Can you please post your publish profile (Project -> PublishProfiles) as well as your `.csproj` file contents?

Comment: Alos what is inside the `x.runtimeconfig.json` file? Something must be up with your local config.

Comment: csproj:

https://ibb.co/gM8b2GJ

Comment: Please add them all as formatted text to the question

Comment: Apologies @ErmiyaEskandary, I've added them to the original post

Comment: What’s the output of the publish command? Add the -v flag for verbosity please